# Variadic macros in C

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

In [GNU documentation on variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html), an example is

> ```c
> #define debug(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> In standard C, you are not allowed to leave the variable argument out entirely; but you are allowed to pass an empty argument. For example, this invocation is invalid in ISO C, because there is no comma after the string:
>
> ```c
> debug ("A message")
> ```

Also GNU gave a solution:

> ```c
> #define debug(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, ## __VA_ARGS__)
> ```

I wonder why not use the below definition

```c
#define debug(...) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

so that it can be compliant with *Standard C*, as well as more concise and intuitive?

Comment: The example in the documentation is just an example. Not every macro can be written with a single `...` argument.

Comment: One reason is that it makes it unclear what you should pass to `debug`. With the explicit `format`, you know what's expected.

Answer (score 1):

```c
#define debug(...) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This allows for `debug()`, which expands to `fprintf (stderr, )`, which is of course invalid syntax.

And with

```c
#define debug(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

using `debug("A message")` similarly becomes `fprintf (stderr, "A message", )`, which as the documentation alludes to, is also an error (and apparently invalid in standard C, which would need `debug("A message", )` which leads to the same flawed expansion). You should just use `debug("%s", "A message")` instead, which works with either definition without relying on compiler specific extensions (and addresses the issue of what happens when the string to print has a % in it).

---

You're looking at documentation for an ancient gcc release; [newer ones](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros) have rewritten that section to be clearer (and have another option besides `##` to address the issue, taken from C++20).